# How to identify an old oscilloscope tube?

Tags: identification, vacuum-tube, cathode-ray-oscilloscope

I have this tube:
[image]
[image]

There is no manufacturer or part number written on it, only the numbers 50321. The first 5 I'm not sure.

Any idea what can it be and what voltages are needed to operate it? It's brand new. Filament glows, getters are intact but did not manage to get a beam on the screen in my scope clock.
Screen diameter is approx 95mm, it has 14 pins + the PDA voltage.

Comment: What do you mean by "the first 5 I'm not sure"?

Comment: is you are unsure of the number, then at least post a picture of it

Comment: Added a picture with the number. Now that it's big I'm quite sure it's an 5. I guess this is probably a serial number, not the part number.

Comment: Draw a diagram showing what you tried. Did you apply high-voltage? You won't get a beam without it.

Comment: I put it into a scope clock that's working with an RFT B13S6 tube. HV is ~1100V. Set max brightness (G1 just a few volts below K), adjusted all other grids to different voltages to no avail, no spot on the screen. This tube is rather complicated, has 2 more grids than the B13S6. I have no idea what the nominal voltages are. Or it might be broken, but how can a tube fail this way?

Comment: That high voltage seems on the low side to me. Is the "scope clock that's working with an RFT B13S6 tub" the same size CRT?

Comment: BTW Are you aware that the wrong high voltage could make the CRT generate x-rays that may be dangerous!?

Comment: Yes the HV might be a bit low, but I'd still expect some image. Somehow there is either no electrons produced or they don't get through the grids/anodes. The B13S6 is 13cm in diameter, and rated for up to 4kV. It's a bit dim in my clock.
X-ray is not a real issue at ~1kV.
I'll try to increase the HV and test with wider range of anode/grid voltages. And then throw away this tube. Would be good to at least know its name :)